# Return code does not seem to affect function behavior

Tags: vba, excel

VBA newbie here. I noticed that the return code on functions don't affect the return value. Am I missing something here.

```
    Private Function test_fn_no_return_code(uc As String)
      test_fn_no_return_code = UCase(uc)
    End Function

    'works the same as 

    Private Function test_fn_no_return_code(uc As String) As String
      test_fn_no_return_code = UCase(uc)
    End Function
```

Comment: This is actually for VB, but it's the same concept: [Type Inference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384937.aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In VBA, a function's return statement takes the form of:

```
Function function_name(args) 
'do stuff...
    function_name = returned_value
    'Or, if returning an Object:
    'Set function_name = returned_object

End Function
```

Both of these functions have a return statement.

```
test_fn_no_return_code = UCase(uc)
```

What the first one doesn't have is an explicit *type*, so it should come through as Variant/String which is implied by the data being returned. In this case, you're just upper-casing the parameter `uc As String`, so you're returning a string.

Comment: thanks. Does the return default to Variant or String.
I spent a lot of time cleaning out unwanted variants that were dragging down performance significantly.

Comment: Unless you explicitly declare type, t will default to return variant. A variant can contain a string. That's what you're seeing.